# I cant load python libraries in cmd, but they work in Anaconda prompt

Tags: python, numpy, cmd, anaconda, sublimetext3

I am trying to load some packages in cmd, but it seems something is wrong in the path. When I try to load it in Anaconda prompt it works fine. The path of python in both environment are same. Pip list shows that the libraries exist in the path. Any help is appreciated.

[here is what happens in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yd9Yl.png)

[the following is what happens in Anacoda prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixSrP.png)

I would like to mention that I checked 
sys.path in both environment are same

Comment: Please also do not post terminal/code output in images. Please see here for why: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/40481

Answer (score 0):

In Anaconda you are working in the `base` environment.

So in cmd use first

```
activate base
```

and only then launch Python:

```
python
```

Comment: is there anyway that I set it as a default because when I am using sublime, I cant load libraries?

Comment: I don't use sublime, so I'm not able to answer you, sorry.